# Return JSON from a Python Class to Another Class

Tags: python, json, google-app-engine

How would I return the **same exact** JSON data from one class to another?

**Code:**

```
class Class1(webapp.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        random_id = str(uuid.uuid1())
        time_now = int(time.time())
        info = {
            id: random_id,
            now: time_now
        }

       json_info = json.dumps(info)
       print json_info
       self.response.write(info)

class Class2(webapp.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        getting_info = self.Class1()
        getting_info_time = getting_info['now']
        print getting_info_time
```

**Error:**

> class1_info = self.Class1()
>
> AttributeError: 'Class2' object has no attribute 'Class1'

---

**Edit (more details):**

One part of my application needs the **whole** JSON output while the other part needs just the `now` value from the *info* dictionary.  And both classes would be using the same **exact** data from the *info* dictionary.

I've been trying to get the `now` output but I just get error messages.

---

**Attempt:**

Note: using @Alex's answer (with @snakecharmerb recommendation of memcache)

**Code:**

```
from google.appengine.api import memcache 

class Class1(webapp.RequestHandler):
    def generate_data(self):
        random_id = str(uuid.uuid1())
        time_now = int(time.time()))

        id_cached = memcache.add(key=random_id, value=random_id, time=600)
        get_id_cached = memcache.get(key=random_id, value=random_id, time=600)

        time_cached = memcache.add(key=time_now, value=time_now, time=600)
        get_time_cached = memcache(key=time_now)

        info = {
            id: get_id_cached,
            now: get_time_cached
        }

       json_info = json.dumps(info)
       return json_info

    def get(self):
        self.response.write(generate_data())

class Class2(webapp.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        getting_info = Class1().generate_data()
        print getting_info
```

Result:

> {"id": "9d752605-a20d-11e7-8bfd-bfe81b332704", "time": "1506356501"}
>
> {"id": "9b95e899-a20d-11e7-b137-bfe81b332704", "time": "1506356498"}

Comment: Welcome to dependency injection! You have to pass the Class1 object to Class2 or simply return `json_info` from Class1.get and then pass it somehow to Class2.get. Your meesage says that Class2 has no member that is Class1

Comment: Thanks for your guidance

Comment: You can actually implement the `__init__` method of Class2 and then have something like `self.cls1 = Class1 ()`

Comment: One part of my application needs the **whole** JSON output while the other part needs just the `now` value from the *info* dictionary. I've been trying to get the `now` output but I just get error messages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would help to know more about what you're trying to do, but based on your code snippet, this should do it.

```
Class1(webapp.RequestHandler):

    @staticmethod
    def perform():
        random_id = str(uuid.uuid1())
        time_now = int(time.time()))
        info = {
            id: random_id,
            now: time_now
        }

       json_info = json.dumps(info)
       print json_info
       return json_info

    def get(self):
       self.response.write(self.perform())

Class2(webapp.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        getting_info = Class1.perform()
        getting_info_time = getting_info['now']
        print getting_info_time
```

Another route would be having Class2 inherit Class1, another route would be moving the 'perform' function outside at the file level. It's hard to give a more appropriate answer without more context.

Edit:
Creating a 'BaseHandler' that both classes inherit seems more appropriate then. Check for existence of the cached ID, if None, create & add.

```
RANDOM_ID = "RANDOM_ID"

MyBaseHandler(webapp.RequestHandler):

    @staticmethod
    def get_random_id():
        cached = memcache.get(key=RANDOM_ID)
        if not cached:
            cached = {id: str(uuid.uuid1()), now: int(time.time()))}
            memcache.add(key=RANDOM_ID, value=cached, time=600)
        return cached

Class1(MyBaseHandler):

    def get(self):
       self.response.write(self.get_random_id())

Class2(MyBaseHandler):
    def get(self):
        print self.get_random_id()['now']
```

Comment: Thank you, this answer was the most helpful in returning JSON (with some minor edits), though the actual values change, which is not the desired outcome. Both classes should have the **same exact** responses and so I edited my question to reflect that requirement. I still upvoted since it does accomplish most of what it should.

Comment: I'm not the most familiar with the intricacies/timing of memcache, but I think editing your code to check for the existence of the memcache key first should do the trick. Also both classes inheriting from a single 'BaseHandler' feels more appropriate now.

Answer (score 1):

If both handlers need to access the same data, delegate the data generation to a function.

```
def generate_data():
    random_id = str(uuid.uuid1())
    time_now = int(time.time()))
    info = {
        id: random_id,
        now: time_now
    }
    return info


Class1(webapp.RequestHandler):

    def get(self):
       info = generate_data()
       json_info = json.dumps(info)
       print json_info
       self.response.write(info)


Class2(webapp.RequestHandler):

    def get(self):
        info = generate_data()
        getting_info_time = info['now']
        print getting_info_time
```

This approach will work if the data is newly generated for each request.  If you need to return the same data for each request then you need to store it for example in the datastore, memcache or a session so that it can be retrieved.

Comment: How would you recommend using *memcache* for the UUID? 

I've been trying `memcache.add` and `memcache.get` with no luck:

`now_set = memcache.add(key=now, value=now, time=300)
now_get = memcache.get(key=now)

info = {
    id: random_id, now: now_get }`

Comment: The values keep changing instead of remaining fixed for 300 seconds. I've reviewed the documentation: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/refdocs/google.appengine.api.memcache and how to use memcache: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/memcache/using. Is there a memcache limitation preventing it from storing the values and returning the same ones for `time=300` or am I using it wrong?

Comment: Memcache isn't garunteed to be reliable unless you pay for the reliable option.  Memcache in appengine really is just that a cache and should not be relied upon.